Infinispan - Spring Boot 3.2.5 Integration javax.transaction error
I am developing a simple Spring Boot app that integrates with Infinispan. My pom is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tsdevelopment</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-cache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-cache</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-spring-boot-starter-remote</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

The following config in application.properties
infinispan.remote.server-list=127.0.0.1:11222
infinispan.remote.auth-username=admin
infinispan.remote.auth-password=admin

And this config class:
import org.infinispan.spring.remote.provider.SpringRemoteCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public SpringRemoteCacheManagerFactoryBean remoteCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        return new SpringRemoteCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(SpringRemoteCacheManagerFactoryBean remoteCacheManagerFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        return remoteCacheManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}

When i run the app i get:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/RollbackException

My understanding is that SpringBoot moved from javax to jakarta transaction API, so i don't want to add a javax dependency to my POM. I am using the most recent version of Infinispan (14.0.32.Final). Is there a way around this? Or is it that Infinispan has not yet moved to jakarta?

Infinispan 14 has both JavaEE and Jakarta artifacts. Infinispan 15 is Jakarta only.

In maven, the versions i see reach up to 14.0.32, not 15. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot-starter-remote/14.0.32.Final

That's the wrong artifact. You want https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot3-starter-remote

You're correct!
